# install4J: incorrect main class in unix bash script

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j 8.0.7 to create java medias.

In my launcher configure java invocation, I got:

- Class Path: `Scan directory .`
- Main Path: `from class path   core.HOLauncher`

However, the generated Unix bash script contains for main class `install4j.core.HOLauncher`

Any idea why `install4j` is prepended to my main class and how I can fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a generated class that is inserted before your main class to enable some features in the install4j runtime.